# SonicWall Routing Between VLANS

Tags: firewall, routing, sonicwall

We have a sonicwall NSA 3500, x4 has 2 vlan interfaces so x4:v300 and x4:v301. Each vlan has an IP v300 is 192.168.100.1 and v301 is 192.168.101.1.

I then have x4 connected to a layer 2 only switch configured ports 1-12 v300 and 13-23 v301 and all 23 ports tagged port 24 then port 24 is tagged for v300 and v301.

I added a firewall access rule to allow subnets on v300 to talk to v301 and vice versa but all I can do is ping hosts on either subnet. Nothing else like ssh or http works.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you read in the FW logs????
You should not use your FW for routing, the best practice recommends the use of a L3 switch, however since are private subnets, you should check the access rule any any from one subnet to the other one.

Comment: Looks like you're missing firewall rules between the 2 VLAN. Have you tried creating 2 simple allow all rules between your 2 VLAN subnets?